# Recreating planes at an industrial level in the 15th century

Tags: technology, technological-development

A portal has opened up in our world, leading to a world which is similar to the technological and cultural level of the the middle ages(15th Century).The Government has figured out how to send people through it, but all their belongings(including their clothes) are lost.

The Government decides to send specialists there to increase their technology till the point that they can produce functional, stable planes which would give them an advantage over other nations in their world.

How many years and specialists would it take to reach that level?

- The Government can be any Government in our world suitable for the task, or an alliance of our Governments.
- The King of their world is willing to work with the government and their specialists.
- The Government can send any(reasonable) amount of specialists they want, however they cannot be used for physical labor.
- The Government can also send any information in the form of books however the materials which the books are made of cannot be used for any purpose.

Comment: Efficient engines would be the major roadblock. You would need a combustion engine - steam engines are too heavy. This, in turn, requires refining oil into gasoline, which in turn requires mining for oil. It may be possible to make an engine run on alcohol, but the power-to-mass ration would be smaller. Sailplabes or airships may be an easier option.

Comment: In real life, it would take about 400 years and thousands of engineers, because in real life it actually took about 400 years and thousands of engineers. In a fantasy novel it would take as many years as the plot requires, and a minimum of one engineer. (Recommended reading: the adventures of [Conrad Stargard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Stargard), Leo Frankowski's Polish *Cross-Time Engineer*.)

Comment: How come that books can go through but clothes cannot? Both clothes and books are made of cellulose fibers.

Comment: @AlexP Due to a scientific phenomenon known as "Plot"

Comment: *the materials which the books are made of cannot be used for any purpose* That makes no sense.

Comment: @StephenG Well, I was trying to make a scenario where only information and experts can go through, so using the books materials would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

| № | Description | Manpower | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0. | Increased food and textiles productivity. Start a vast program to increase productivity of basic production of food and textiles. In the 15th century most men were busy growing food, and most women were busy spinning yarn and weaving cloth. You need to free them up to pick up the new trades required for the new technologies. Send a team of experts to introduce modern-ish (= about 1800) agricultural technology and early modern (= about 1750) spinning and weaving technology. This will require unwavering dedication from the king and the assent of the ruling classes, who will see their power base evaporate. This work stream must continue throughout the program. The goal is that 20 to 30 years after the start of the program the fraction of the workforce engaged in food and textiles production will drop to about 20 to 25%. | 10 | 25 |
| 1. | Basic mathematics. To make airplanes, the engines and weapons for airplanes, the materials of which the airframes, the engines and the weapons are made, the fuel, the machines and tools for making the airframes, the engines, the weapons and the fuel, they need late-19th century algebra and calculus. Need to send a set of good books, starting from grade 1 to college level; remember that people in the 15th century had no idea of anything even remotely resembling modern mathematical notation, and calculus was not even in their dreams. They knew *some* algebra, but it was still very primitive. In parallel, start a massive alphabetization program; you will need lots and lots of literate workers. You cannot develop modern technology with a medieval workforce. | 4 | 10 |
| 2. | Pencils and paper. To learn mathematics and physics and chemistry, they will surely need pencils and decent, cheap paper. Surprise, they didn't have either pencils or decent, cheap paper. Send somebody who knows how to make artisanal pencils and pencil leads. Send somebody who knows how a late 18th century paper factory worked. Send somebody who can build the water-powered machinery for the factory. | 3 | 2 |
| 3. | Units of measurement and measurement instruments. In the 15th century words such as inch, yard, ounce, pound and so on had very imprecise meanings, varying from place to place, from workshop to workshop, and from worker to worker. There was no way to order, for example, an axle exactly 152 inches long with a diameter of exactly 5¾ inches and expect to receive an axle which will fit. They had no notion of interchangeable parts; each and every thing, a piece of furniture, a machine, a house, was unique and not repeatable. To introduce uniform units of measurement will require tremendous political effort from the king. To introduce uniform units of measurement with the required precision for building aircraft, engines and weapons will require a lot of effort, a lot of money and a lot of work. Send a group of engineers who really know their stuff about metrology, and a group of economists and political advisors who can support the king in this endeavour. | 9 | 10 |
| 4. | Machine tools. You will need to introduce a large number of machine tools which simply did not exist in the 15th century. Modern lathes. Presses. Roll mills. Even modern-ish workbenches were unknown. Send a group of engineers who really know how modern machine tools developed historically and can recreate mid-19th century industrial machine tools. This will take a lot of political good will, and a lot of money. Best bet is to introduce steam power as a stepping stone. | 12 | 10 |
| 5. | Chemistry and metallurgy. Chemistry did not exist as such in the 15th century. Metallurgy was a purely empirical trade, with no theoretical basis whatsoever. All this will have to be recreated from scratch, starting with the glass of which test tubes are made. Send a suitably chosen group of chemists and metallurgists to teach and train a larger group of chemists and metallurgists. Note that you must have completed points 2 and 3 above, and at least half of points 1 and 4 before starting this effort. | 12 | 10 |
| 6. | Raw materials. You will need to establish mines for raw materials which did not exist in the 15th century. You will need to establish trade relationships with sources of raw materials which were not available in the 15th century in your chosen country. Metals, rubber, petroleum, shellac such stuff. Note that mines take a long time to become productive on an industrial scale. This needs to come after completing at least half of points 4 and 5 above. | 20 | 10 |
| 7. | Technical drawings, heliography and lithography. Those engineers and mechanical workers will need lots of technical drawings, and will need access to a technology to multiplicate blueprints. Manuals will also need to be multiplicated. You need to teach them technical drawing, and you need to introduce tracing paper, a blueprint process (either cyanotype or diazo, your choice) and practicable lithography. This needs to come after about two thirds of point 5 above have been completed. | 6 | 2 |
| 8. | Airframes and engines. Congratulations! About 25 or 30 years have passed, and your target country has reached the technological level where they can begin experimenting with airframes and aircraft engines. Of course, the new technology has now permeated all society, and neighboring countries are busy copying it. The social fabric and the economical structure of the country are very different from what they were when all this transformation started. (For example, because all this modern technological base needs a vast pool of literate and relatively well paid workforce. We are no long in the middle ages, not at all.) The old king has died and a new king is on the throne. Wars have been fought. *This is when you send aircraft engineers:* they would have been utterly useless before this point. Allow for about 5 years to develop practicable aircraft. | 20 | 5 |
| 9. | Weapons. Air power need *both* aircraft and weapons suitable for use; this means machine guns and bombs. Send the appropriate kind of engineers and chemists. Note that you must start developing fire weapons and explosives long before this point, because the prosperity induced by the technological transformations will make the target country a coveted object of desire for invidious neighbors. | 10 | 5 |

Comment: But where do you get the manpower to actually implement all this stuff? Some 80-90% of the total population will be focused on agriculture. There simply isn't a big pool of people who can train in mathematics or metallurgy or chemistry. As you point out, you're not getting very far with a medieval workforce, and the vast majority of the population will remain exactly that.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: I alluded to the social and economic changes needed to bring it all about. I will edit the answer to make it clear than a separate stream of activity is needed to increase productivity so that a significant fraction of the workforce can become available for industrial use.

Answer (score 1):

It would take fewer than 36 months (Earth time) to have aircraft rolling off the assembly line.

And when I say assembly line, I mean just that... not one-off artisan-style vehicles, but standardized machines in which a part from one can substitute in any other. The idea of that hadn't developed in the 15th century, but as an idea it is easily transported through the portal/stargate/wormhole in the head of any expert you can coerce to go through. Furthermore, many of these experts would readily understand all of the prerequisites necessary to make it a reality (most are logistical, though some are mechanical... tolerances and so forth).

Really, the biggest time waste of this exercise is finding and scouting out the materials necessary. The inhabitants can help with that, presumably, and shave a few months off the time table. But since you are looking for particular sorts of wood and textiles for which near-substitutes might be unsuitable, that only goes so far and relies a bit on luck. Furthermore, this being a logistical problem, securing sufficient quantities and other resources will be just as important.

The aircraft themselves will be lightweight, unpowered gliders. Similar to those used today recreationally. Training won't be possible until the first prototype is complete, but trainer pilots can be sent through as well. With enough expertise these gliders will be able to stay aloft up to 10-12 hours. Their military capacity will be extensive. Strategically, they can see far beyond the horizon of those people still standing down on the ground and can keep track of troop movements and other military exercises (at sea too). Tactically they can survey the battlefield and relay commands (radio is almost out of reach, but possible... even without though semaphore signalling of some type should be doable).

I'm even wondering if you could do limited paratrooping. These will be two-seaters, so that's only one passenger per aircraft, but in some conflicts even being able to rapidly put a dozen soldiers on the ground where the enemy doesn't think it possible for your forces to be can win a battle. The altitude of the gliders is sufficient, but pre-modern rope and textiles are a little janky. Your comfort level with that probably has more to do with whether you'll personally be parachuting or if you're sending off some stranger's kid to do it.

As a bonus, airships, either hydrogen or hot air, are doable well within this time frame too. Some military applications for those also, though more limited.

Modern aircraft are probably out on anything less than a 30-40 year time frame. Just not going to get radar, internal combustion engines, or if you're just being facetious, no guided missiles or mini-guns. (Now, on the other hand... rockets? Maybe.)

I leave it as an exercise for the reader if they can do all this without bankrupting the economy. This is not an air superiority military, the aircraft can only support and enhance a proper army/navy. So if you spend all the gold making these things, do you still have the army and/or navy to actually win engagements?